# Why doesn't my trigger work?

Tags: mysql, triggers

My trigger:

```
create trigger cnt after insert on tc_contract
  for each rowbegin
    select count(*) into @num from tc_contract group by account_id where account_id = new.account_id;
    if @num >0 and @num <3 then
      update tc_account set account_status = 2 where account_id = new.account_id;
    end if;
end
```

The error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near 'where account_id = new.account_id;
if @num >0 and @num <3 then update tc_accou' at line 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `WHERE` clause before the `GROUP BY` clause.

i.e.

```
select count(*)
into @num
from tc_contract
where account_id = new.account_id
group by account_id;
```